# Gatsby Image inside Flickity carousel

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, flickity, gatsby-image

I am creating a gatsby website that uses the [flickity-react-component](https://github.com/theolampert/react-flickity-component) to display a slider with product images. I believe that I should use the gatsby image to make it load faster, but when I try it, the Image does not display (it is 0x0 pixels).

This is the code I am trying to run:

```
const ThirdPage = ({ data }) => {
...

function Carousel() {
    return (
        <Flickity
            className={'carousel'} // default ''
            elementType={'div'} // default 'div'
            options={flickityOptions} // takes flickity options {}
            disableImagesLoaded={false} // default false
            reloadOnUpdate // default false
            static // default false
        >
            <Img fluid={data.imgPrincipal.childImageSharp.fluid} alt="Mulher a lavar o cabelo com o chuveiro ecológico" />
            <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature" />
            <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature" />
            <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/architecture" />
        </Flickity>
    );
}
```

The "Img" is the one using the gatsby image, the others are what I had before.

[This is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAPqY.png)

I don't get an error when running this, I believe this might be because gatsby-image creates a `div`.

Can someone help me make this work? I am a beginner, so if it's something very advanced, I would appreciate an alternative ... Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, `gatsby-image` is not only a simple image. It creates a wrapper with a few nested `div` HTML structure inside to make the blur effect and the rest of the improvements.

Take a look at [`gatsby-image` docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-image/):

> *Note: `gatsby-image` is not a drop-in replacement for `<img />`. It’s
> optimized for fixed width/height images and images that stretch the
> full-width of a container. Some ways you can use `<img />` won’t work
> with `gatsby-image`.*

It may not work with all sliders.

I've used it with other sliders that accept a nested structure inside, not only a single `<img>` tag such as [Swiper](https://swiperjs.com/) or [Slick](https://react-slick.neostack.com/).

Comment: Thank you. I will check those out. Which one was simpler to implement with gatsby-image, in your opinion? It's mainly for mobile.

Comment: Swiper is much more lighter, I prefer it upon Slick